# Can only get first row in table when scraping with Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape rank data from [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/search/boardgame?sort=rank&advsearch=1&q=&include%5Bdesignerid%5D=&include%5Bpublisherid%5D=&geekitemname=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bminage%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bnumvoters%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Bnumweights%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Bminplayers%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bmaxplayers%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Bleastplaytime%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Bplaytime%5D%5Bmax%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmax%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmax%5D=&colfiltertype=&searchuser=&playerrangetype=normal&B1=Submit).

The basic structure of the HTML is like:

```html
<table class = "collection_table">
<tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="row_"></tr>
    <tr id="row_"></tr>
    <tr id="row_"></tr>
    <tr id="row_"></tr>
    <!--snip-->
    <tr id="row_"></tr>
    <tr id="row_"></tr>
    <tr id="row_"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that every row except the first (a header) has the same id, and no extra data to mark it as a unique row.

My (current) code is as follows:

```
def bgg_scrape_rank_page(browser, bgg_data):
    time.sleep(1)
    table = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='collection_table']/tbody")
    row = table.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='row_']")
    while row:
        rank = row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[1]").text
        game_name = row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[3]/div[2]/a").text
        game_page = row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[3]/div[2]/a").get_attribute("href")
        print rank, game_name, game_page
        row = row.find_element_by_xpath("//following-sibling::tr")
```

I have also tried iterating using

```
rows = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/tr[@id='row_']")
for row in rows:
    rank = row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[1]").text
    game_name = row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[3]/div[2]/a").text
    game_page = row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[3]/div[2]/a").get_attribute("href")
    print rank, game_name, game_page
```

The problem is, no matter what I seem to try, I always only get the first row printed out. Just row after row of

```
1 "Pandemic Legacy: Season 1 https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/161936/pandemic-legacy-season-1".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `XPath`: you need to add dot as `.//` to point on exact context where you want to apply `XPath` instead of just `//` that always points on `<html>`. So try

```
def bgg_scrape_rank_page(browser, bgg_data):
time.sleep(1)
table = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='collection_table']/tbody")
row = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[@id='row_']")
while row:
    rank = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[1]").text
    game_name = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[3]/div[2]/a").text
    game_page = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[3]/div[2]/a").get_attribute("href")
    print rank, game_name, game_page
    row = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//following-sibling::tr")
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why I was still getting a "rows" list of size 100 before, when every element was the same?

Comment: `XPath` `//tr[@id='row_']` matches all `tr` elements with `id='row_'` on page. It seem to be a development issue as `id` has to be unique identifier that should be set to single element only. In your case you might need to use indexes to identify each element...